# Implementing modified binary search in python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

The problem is to find the index of the element which is less than or equal to N. To tackle the problem, I wrote the following code but it seems to be not working.

```
def find_index(primes, N, start, end):
    mid = int((start + end)/2)
    if start == end:
    return start

    if primes[mid - 1] < N: 
        if primes[mid] == N:
            return mid
        elif primes[mid] > N:
            return mid - 1
        else:
            return find_index(primes, N, start, mid + 1)
    elif primes[mid - 1] > N:
        if primes[mid] > N:
            return find_index(primes, N, mid - 1, end)
```

What obvious condition am I missing? Is there any better method to find the index in O(log(n))?

Comment: There is bisect in python. So if you are not doing this in educational purposes, use it. If in educational - show how you debugged your script.

Comment: Please be more precise than *"seems to be not working"*.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, I'm using it for educational purposes and thanks for the suggestion. I will try to find working of Bisect module.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Seems not to be working means infinite loop.

Comment: @Manu so **edit the question** to include that information. Have you thought about putting some `print`s in to see how the state is evolving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of size 2 or larger, divide and conquer:

```
def find_index(primes, N, start, end):
    mid = int((start + end)/2)

    if start == end:
        return start

    if end - start == 1:
        return end if primes[end] < N else start

    if primes[mid] == N:
      return mid
    elif primes[mid] < N:
        return find_index(primes, N, mid, end)
    else:
        return find_index(primes, N, start, mid)
```

The logic here being that choosing sublists via midpoint will eventually yield a difference between `start` and `end` of `1`. This can be assumed for the following reasons:

1. Since `(start + end)/2 = floor((start + end)/2)`, the midpoint will eventually be 1 index away from the upper boundary.
2. A list of size 2 (e.g. start/end 3/4 or 2/3) will always yield a list of size 2 since the midpoint will be the lower bound. This is evident given `(n + n + 1)/2 = (2n + 1)/2 => 2n/2 = n`.

Once a difference of `1` has been reached, the top and bottom can be checked for satisfying the requirement of being `less than N`.

Completely empty list case not handled.